# Reference variables from package calculator in TiKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations

I have this code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[letterpaper, landscape, margin=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\pgfplotsset{width=15cm,compat=1.9}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\allowdisplaybreaks  
\usepackage{calculator} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}


\begin{document}

\COPY{0.5}{\d_h_relation} % d/h relation

\COPY{1.4}{\h} % Plate thickness
\MULTIPLY{\d_h_relation}{\h}{\equivalent_circle_diameter}
\MULTIPLY{\equivalent_circle_diameter}{\equivalent_circle_diameter}{\A_part_1}
\MULTIPLY{\A_part_1}{\numberPI}{\A_part_2}
\DIVIDE{\A_part_2}{4}{\Area}% Area of the hole.
\SQUAREROOT{\Area}{\temp1r_h11}
\DIVIDE{\temp1r_h11}{2}{\temp2r_h11}

\COPY{6.304640974884}{\r1} % Central radius of the first hole.
\SUBTRACT{\r1}{\temp2r_h11}{\rh11} % Internal radius of hole 1.
$\rh11$
\ADD{\r1}{\temp2r_h11}{\rh12} % External radius of hole 1
$\rh12$
\DIVIDE{1}{\r1}{\theta_hs1_part1}
\MULTIPLY{\temp2r_h11}{\theta_hs1_part1}{\theta_hs1}
\COPY{0.187226105362745}{\varph1} % angle of the first hole.
\SUBTRACT{\varph1}{\theta_hs1}{\thetarad11_rad} % angle in radians of the first border of hole 1
\DIVIDE{\thetarad11_rad}{\numberPI}{\thetadeg11_part1}
\MULTIPLY{\thetadeg11_part1}{180}{\thetadeg11}
$\thetadeg11$
\ADD{\varph1}{\theta_hs1}{\thetarad12_rad} % angle in radians of the second border of hole 1
\DIVIDE{\thetarad12_rad}{\numberPI}{\thetadeg12_part1}
\MULTIPLY{\thetadeg12_part1}{180}{\thetadeg12}
$\thetadeg12$

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) circle [radius=10.75cm];
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=4.2cm];

\begin{scope}[even odd rule]
\draw[fill=gray!20,thick] (0,0) circle [radius=8cm] circle [radius=6cm];
\end{scope}

\draw[fill=white] (7.908394:5.994461) node (a1) {} arc[radius=5.994461, start angle=7.908394, end angle= 13.546137] --  (13.546137:6.61482) node (a2) {} arc[radius=6.61482, start angle=13.546137, end angle= 7.908394] -- cycle;
\path (a1) -- (a2) node[inner sep=2pt,circle,fill,pos=0.5] (x1) {};

\draw (0,0) -- (x1) node[pos=0.5,fill=white,circle] {$r_1$};

\draw (0,0) -- ++(3.5,0);

\draw[->] (0:2.5cm) arc (0:10.72:2.5cm) node[pos=0.5,label={0:$\varphi_1$}] {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I want to use the variables: "`rh11`, `rh12`, `thetadeg11` and `thetadeg12`"
,calculated with the calculator package before the TiKZpicture,
for use as coordinates of the hole in the TiKZpicture. I Have tried with this:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[letterpaper, landscape, margin=0in]{geometry}        
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\pgfplotsset{width=15cm,compat=1.9}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\allowdisplaybreaks  
\usepackage{calculator} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}


\begin{document}    
\COPY{0.5}{\d_h_relation} % d/h relation
\COPY{1.4}{\h} % Plate thickness
\MULTIPLY{\d_h_relation}{\h}{\equivalent_circle_diameter}
\MULTIPLY{\equivalent_circle_diameter}{\equivalent_circle_diameter}{\A_part_1}
\MULTIPLY{\A_part_1}{\numberPI}{\A_part_2}
\DIVIDE{\A_part_2}{4}{\Area}% Area of the hole.
\SQUAREROOT{\Area}{\temp1r_h11}
\DIVIDE{\temp1r_h11}{2}{\temp2r_h11}

\COPY{6.304640974884}{\r1} % Central radius of the first hole.
\SUBTRACT{\r1}{\temp2r_h11}{\rh11} % Internal radius of hole 1.
$\rh11$
\ADD{\r1}{\temp2r_h11}{\rh12} % External radius of hole 1
$\rh12$
\DIVIDE{1}{\r1}{\theta_hs1_part1}
\MULTIPLY{\temp2r_h11}{\theta_hs1_part1}{\theta_hs1}
\COPY{0.187226105362745}{\varph1} % angle of the first hole.
\SUBTRACT{\varph1}{\theta_hs1}{\thetarad11_rad} % angle in radians of the first border of hole 1
\DIVIDE{\thetarad11_rad}{\numberPI}{\thetadeg11_part1}
\MULTIPLY{\thetadeg11_part1}{180}{\thetadeg11}
$\thetadeg11$
\ADD{\varph1}{\theta_hs1}{\thetarad12_rad} % angle in radians of the second border of hole 1
\DIVIDE{\thetarad12_rad}{\numberPI}{\thetadeg12_part1}
\MULTIPLY{\thetadeg12_part1}{180}{\thetadeg12}
$\thetadeg12$

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) circle [radius=10.75cm];
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=4.2cm];

\begin{scope}[even odd rule]
\draw[fill=gray!20,thick] (0,0) circle [radius=8cm] circle [radius=6cm];
\end{scope}

\draw[fill=white] (\thetadeg11:\rh11) node (a1) {} arc[radius=\rh11, start angle=\thetadeg11, end angle= \thetadeg12] --  (\thetadeg12:\rh12) node (a2) {} arc[radius=\rh12, start angle=\thetadeg12, end angle= \thetadeg11] -- cycle;
    \path (a1) -- (a2) node[inner sep=2pt,circle,fill,pos=0.5] (x1) {};

\draw (0,0) -- (x1) node[pos=0.5,fill=white,circle] {$r_1$};

\draw (0,0) -- ++(3.5,0);

\draw[->] (0:2.5cm) arc (0:10.72:2.5cm) node[pos=0.5,label={0:$\varphi_1$}] {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But it does not compile, it shows en error warning. How can I reference them?.

Comment: You could probably use `pgfmath` instead of `calculator`, e.g. `\pgfmathsetmacro{\foo}{3*sin(60)}` calculates the product of 3 and the sine of 60 degrees and saves it to the macro `\foo`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Torbjørn T'.'s suggestion is the cleanest way to proceed here. Nevertheless, as some sort of academic exercise (or even more, depending on how you view things), in the following I show a rather simple way to make things work. Let me, however, stress that

> this code throws several pstricks-related warnings which I did not try to make disappear.

I have been using pstricks for more than a decade, and just recently switched to Ti*k*Z. I always loved using pstricks and am really grateful to those who wrote and maintain that great package. However, unfortunately I cannot find enough motivation any more to find out what the sometimes arguably somewhat cryptic warnings mean.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[letterpaper, landscape, margin=0in]{geometry}        
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\pgfplotsset{width=15cm,compat=1.9}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\allowdisplaybreaks  
\usepackage{calculator} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}


\begin{document}    
\COPY{0.5}{\d_h_relation} % d/h relation
\COPY{1.4}{\h} % Plate thickness
\MULTIPLY{\d_h_relation}{\h}{\equivalent_circle_diameter}
\MULTIPLY{\equivalent_circle_diameter}{\equivalent_circle_diameter}{\A_part_1}
\MULTIPLY{\A_part_1}{\numberPI}{\A_part_2}
\DIVIDE{\A_part_2}{4}{\Area}% Area of the hole.
\SQUAREROOT{\Area}{\temp1r_h11}
\DIVIDE{\temp1r_h11}{2}{\temp2r_h11}

\COPY{6.304640974884}{\r1} % Central radius of the first hole.
\SUBTRACT{\r1}{\temp2r_h11}{\rh11} % Internal radius of hole 1.
$\rh11$
\xdef\tmpa{\rh11}
%\typeout{\tmpa}
\ADD{\r1}{\temp2r_h11}{\rh12} % External radius of hole 1
$\rh12$
\xdef\tmpb{\rh12}
\typeout{\tmpb}
\DIVIDE{1}{\r1}{\theta_hs1_part1}
\MULTIPLY{\temp2r_h11}{\theta_hs1_part1}{\theta_hs1}
\COPY{0.187226105362745}{\varph1} % angle of the first hole.
\SUBTRACT{\varph1}{\theta_hs1}{\thetarad11_rad} % angle in radians of the first border of hole 1
\DIVIDE{\thetarad11_rad}{\numberPI}{\thetadeg11_part1}
\MULTIPLY{\thetadeg11_part1}{180}{\thetadeg11}
$\thetadeg11$
\xdef\tmpc{\thetadeg11}
%\typeout{\tmpc}
\ADD{\varph1}{\theta_hs1}{\thetarad12_rad} % angle in radians of the second border of hole 1
\DIVIDE{\thetarad12_rad}{\numberPI}{\thetadeg12_part1}
\MULTIPLY{\thetadeg12_part1}{180}{\thetadeg12}
$\thetadeg12$
\xdef\tmpd{\thetadeg12}
%\typeout{\tmpd}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) circle [radius=10.75cm];
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=4.2cm];

\begin{scope}[even odd rule]
\draw[fill=gray!20,thick] (0,0) circle [radius=8cm] circle [radius=6cm];
\end{scope}

 \draw[fill=white] (\tmpc:\tmpa) coordinate (a1) 
 arc[radius=\tmpa, start angle=\tmpc, end angle= \tmpd] --  
 (\tmpd:\tmpb) coordinate (a2)  arc[radius=\tmpb, start angle=\tmpd, end angle=
 \tmpc] -- cycle;
  \path (a1) -- (a2) node[inner sep=2pt,circle,fill,pos=0.5] (x1) {};

\draw (0,0) -- (x1) node[pos=0.5,fill=white,circle] {$r_1$};

\draw (0,0) -- ++(3.5,0);

\draw[->] (0:2.5cm) arc (0:10.72:2.5cm) node[pos=0.5,label={0:$\varphi_1$}] {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think @marmot answer already addressed the original query, this answer explains how to use another way to compute the quantities.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
%\usepackage[letterpaper, landscape, margin=0in]{geometry}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\pgfplotsset{width=15cm,compat=1.9}
%\usepackage{pstricks}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
%\usepackage{bigstrut}
% \allowdisplaybreaks  
%\usepackage{calculator} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}

\usepackage{xintexpr}
\newcommand\xuse[1]{\xinttheiexpr[6]#1\relax}% rounds and format to fixed point
                                             % with 6 fractional decimal digits 
% 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944...
\xintdeffloatvar Pi := 3.141592653589793;% rounded to 16 digits of precision


\begin{document}

\xintdeffloatvar doverh := 0.5; % d/h relation
\xintdeffloatvar h := 1.4; %  Plate thickness
\xintdeffloatvar equivalent_circle_diameter := doverh * h;
\xintdeffloatvar Area := Pi * equivalent_circle_diameter^2/4;
\xintdeffloatvar temp2r_h11 := sqrt(Area)/2;

\xintdeffloatvar r1 := 6.304640974884; % Central radius of the first hole.
\xintdeffloatvar rh11 := r1 - temp2r_h11; % Internal radius of hole 1.
\xintdeffloatvar rh12 := r1 + temp2r_h11;%  External radius of hole 1

\xintdeffloatvar theta_hs1 := temp2r_h11 /r1;
\xintdeffloatvar varph1 :=  0.187226105362745; % angle of the first hole.

\xintdeffloatvar thetarad11_rad := varph1 - theta_hs1; % angle in radians of the first border of hole 1
\xintdeffloatvar thetadeg11 := 180 * thetarad11_rad/Pi;

\xintdeffloatvar thetarad12_rad := varph1 + theta_hs1; % angle in radians of second border of hole 1
\xintdeffloatvar thetadeg12 := 180 * thetarad12_rad/Pi;

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) circle [radius=10.75cm];
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=4.2cm];

\begin{scope}[even odd rule]
\draw[fill=gray!20,thick] (0,0) circle [radius=8cm] circle [radius=6cm];
\end{scope}

\draw[fill=white] 
 (\xuse{thetadeg11}:\xuse{rh11}) 
  node (a1) {}
   arc[radius=\xuse{rh11},
       start angle=\xuse{thetadeg11},
       end angle=\xuse{thetadeg12}] 
 --  
 (\xuse{thetadeg12}:\xuse{rh12})
  node (a2) {}
   arc[radius=\xuse{rh12},
       start angle=\xuse{thetadeg12},
       end angle= \xuse{thetadeg11}]
 -- cycle;

\path (a1) -- (a2) node[inner sep=2pt,circle,fill,pos=0.5] (x1) {};

\draw (0,0) -- (x1) node[pos=0.5,fill=white,circle] {$r_1$};

\draw (0,0) -- ++(3.5,0);

\draw[->] (0:2.5cm) arc (0:10.72:2.5cm) node[pos=0.5,label={0:$\varphi_1$}] {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Remark: the rounding step to 6 fractional decimal digits will be done (from 16 digits float precision) on each use of macro `\xuse`.  If the variables are to be used many times it is also possible to do the rounding in advance and store the result in a macro to be used inside the TikZ syntax (which obviously allows such macros at these spots, if they act expandably -- from experience with `coordinates` I know that sometimes not much than 100 expansion steps are allowed, I don't know if this restriction applies here).

[image]